# css transition with javascript has no transition

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, transition

when I try to make a simple transition with pure CSS all works fine.
But when I try to call a javascript-function which modiefies the CSS when clicked on a link, there is no transition. I want to fade in a grey layer.

HTML:

```
<a href="someImage.jpg" id="test">
    <img src="someImage.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<section id="grey"> 
</section>
```

JS:

```
var grey = document.getElementById("grey");
var link = document.getElementById("test");
link.onclick = function () {
    grey.style.display = "block";
    grey.style.opacity = "1";
    return false;
};
```

CSS:

```
section {
    display:none;
    size and position...
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: opacity 1s .5s;
}
```

(see http://jsfiddle.net/7zEhx/5/ )

I'm using FF22, does anyone know any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`display: none` elements don’t transition, and the `display: block` hasn’t kicked in before you set the other style. There are horrible hacks like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    grey.style.opacity = "1";
}, 0);
```

But I’d just set `width` to `0` instead of setting `display` and then put it back at `100%`.
[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/7zEhx/6/)

Comment: Why is this hack working? seems like it just sets the opacity with no delay.

Comment: @raam86: Passing `0` to `setTimeout` makes it wait until everything synchronous is done, since JavaScript is single-threaded.

Comment: That's actually a nice hack.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Using the width is a very simple solution, but I just couldn't think of it. However I think in my case it's easier to use your "hack". One thing I found out is that setTimeout(..., 0) will not always work, especially when I'm changing the display of one element which contains a lot of other elements. If I use a higher timeout it's more reliable, but It's still nonsatisfying.